# Why doesn't JScrollPane work when it is added to BorderLayout.NORTH?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, border-layout

I want to add a `JScrollPane` to a `JFrame`, and attach to its top, because if it fits on the frame, the panel in the scrollpane appears centered.The panel in the scrollpane has `GridBagLayout`, and has multiple panels on it, aligned from top to bottom.
This is the code of how I display it:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame(item.props.get("name"));
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0x202020));
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(new Weapon(item, tags, main));
scroll.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0x202020), 2), new LineBorder(new Color(0x202020), 2)));
scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(24);
frame.getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
frame.setSize(size.width/2, size.height/2);
frame.setLocation((int) (size.width*0.25), (int) (size.height*0.25));
frame.setVisible(true);
```

When the scrollpane is added to `BorderLayout.NORTH`, it looks like the aim has been achieved, but when there's need for the scrollbar, it doesn't apear.
If it is added to `BorderLayout.CENTER`, it works, but it's centered, which I want to avoid.

How could this layout be achieved?

Comment: Instead of the JFrame setSize method, use pack.  The JScrollPane is designed to be used with [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).  You could also create a JPanel with a BorderLayout, put the JScrollPane in the center, and put the JPanel in the BEFORE_FIRST_LINE of the JFrame.

Comment: JFrame.pack() sets the frame size to cover all of its content, which makes an scrollpane unnecessary, and the window may be bigger than the screen, according to the needed size.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.